# xhtml: using '#' in a value attribute makes the characters after '#' being ignored

Tags: java, primefaces, xhtml, javabeans

First of all, sorry for the bad title but I don't know how to describe it better.

My problem:

I want to display pictures in a `<p:lightbox>` element. Unfortunately the pictures contain '#' characters in their fileneame, so they look like this for example: desert_#1#.jpg.

Here is my code:

```
<p:panel id="showPics" closable="false" header="Fotos: ">
      <p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox">  
          <p:dataList value="#{myBean.fotoList}" var="fl" >
              <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/pics/#{fl.PictureName}" title="#{fl.PictureName}" >  
                    <h:graphicImage value="#{request.contextPath}/resources/pics/#{fl.PictureName}"/>  
              </h:outputLink>          
          </p:dataList>
     </p:lightBox> 
</p:panel>
```

the beanvalue #{fl.PictureName} returns the filename, so in our example desert_#1#.jpg

Now when I'm running my application, I get this error message:

> Problem accessing /resources/pics/desert_. Reason: Not Found

So my guess is that the # characters in the picturename are recognized as references (or whatever you call them) to a beanmethod/value, which they of course aren't. Therefore the string after the first '#' in the filename isn't recognized anymore. 
Unfortunately I cannot simply change the filename to get rid of the '#'s.

Could somebody tell me how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: I'm using JSF2.0 with Primefaces and Primefaces mobile components (since my application is a mobile web application) and Spring webflow framework. My IDE is Netbeans.

Comment: Could you please clarify how the XML input is handled by your application? How you read it? Which API call you use to resolve the bean values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the server side, encode the bean value using [URI percent encoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html). In this case, the property should use `%23` where `#` is in the filename.